# CoreOS Systemd sidekick unit unable to start

Tags: systemd, coreos

I have a service with this for a sidekick unit and keep receiving the error:
[/run/fleet/units/tomcat-discovery@1.service:11] Trailing garbage, ignoring.
tomcat-discovery@1.service has no ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for RemainAfterExit=yes services. Refusing.

I have seemingly tried every different combination I can think of and have successfully tested the command from the terminal without issue.  If I remove the first call to etcdctl the second set command also works in the service file without issue.  Any ideas as to where I am going wrong here?

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat web server etcd registration

# Requirements
Requires=etcd.service
Requires=tomcat@%i.service

# Dependency ordering and binding
After=etcd.service
After=tomcat@%i.service
BindsTo=tomcat@%i.service

[Service]

# Get CoreOS environmental variables
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

# Start

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "\
while true; do \
    etcdctl set /services/tomcat/tomcat-%i/ip ${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:$(docker inspect --format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8080/tcp") 0).HostPort}}' tomcat.%i) --ttl 180; \
    etcdctl set /services/bind/tomcat-%i ${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4} --ttl 180; \
  sleep 60; \
done"

# Stop
ExecStop=/usr/bin/etcdctl rm --recursive /services/tomcat/tomcat-%i

[X-Fleet]
# Schedule on the same machine as the associated Apache service
MachineOf=tomcat@%i.service
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to correct the error by using single quotes around the /bin/bash -c command, using double quotes around the --format and double escape the port number.  The final full ExecStart command is:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
while true; do \
  etcdctl set /services/tomcat/tomcat-%i/ip ${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:$(docker inspect --format="{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports \\"8080/tcp\\") 0).HostPort}}" tomcat.%i) --ttl 180; \
  etcdctl set /services/bind/tomcat-%i ${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4} --ttl 180; \
sleep 60; \
done'
```